# What happens if I use a style an API version doesn't support

Tags: java, android

I want to use the following style:

```
  <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground" tools:ignore="NewApi">@drawable/blank</item>
```

However, to do so, I have to use an API version above my apps minimum. If I do decide to use this style, will API's below the supporting version just ignore this style, or will this cause an application failure?

Comment: Can't you just try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Your application will show errors when building. I don't think you can deploy an application to an AVD, or test device if it has active errors.

You can create though folders designated for newer-older API levels and try to bypass your issue like this.

[image: Creating folders for each API version needed.]

Also, check out the official Android Docs.  [click me!](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html)